# Grant access to a subfolder and keep the folder directory

Tags: sharepoint-online

Suppose admin account have the following specific subfolder in **workspace1** to share with a employee:
**'Documents > _Projects > layer1 > layer2 > ise'**
and don't want employee to read/write anything else in other documents.

But when the employee sync the folder, it appears as
**'.../workspace1/workspace1 - ise'.**
I want to ask how can I make it appears as
**'.../workspace1/workspace1 - Documents/_Projects/layer1/layer2/ise'?**
So that it can remain consistent with the project directory?

Answer (score 0):

Users need at least Edit permission to sync files in the library to OneDrive for Business.

So to achieve this requirement:

1. The user needs access to all folders to sync all folder structures.
2. The user cannot read/write anything else in this library, so it has only access to the document itself.

The only solution is to give unique permission to every document/folder in this library so that the user can sync all folders but see only one document inside.